# Reading RGB8 buffer from OpenGL ES 3.0 on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-3.0

I really need to get an RGB 8 bytes per channel buffer from the GPU.
I need it to pass to a trained convolutional neural network, and it only accepts data in that format.
I can't convert it on the CPU as I'm heavily CPU bound and it's quite slow.

I currently have FBO with a renderbuffer attached, which is defined with:

`glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB8_OES, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);`

There are no errors when I bind, define and render to the buffer.

But when I use 

`glReadPixels(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgbBufferRawName);`

it gives an invalid enum error (0x0500). It works just fine when I pass `GL_RED_EXT` or `GL_RGBA` and produces correct buffers (I've checked it by uploading those buffers to a texture and rendering them, and they looked correct).

I tried setting `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` but that made no difference.

I'm on iOS10 and iPhone 6. I was doing ES2.0, but now tried switching to ES3.0 in hopes that it will help me solve the problem. It did not.

I would really appreciate help in getting RGB8 buffer in any way,
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that instead of a FBO with render buffer you use a FBO with a color texture attachment (and depth attachment if you need a depth buffer), then use glGetTextureImage to read the data from it. glGetTextureImage accepts GL_RGB format while glReadPixels does not.

Comment: @VB_overflow `glGetTextureImage` is not available on OpenGL ES 3.0 =(

Comment: My bad, sorry. In this case I would suggest using a PBO like described [here](https://vec.io/posts/faster-alternatives-to-glreadpixels-and-glteximage2d-in-opengl-es). With this method you get a ptr to the RGBA pixel data, so instead of doing a memcpy like in the example you could do a loop which will only copy 3 bytes (RGB), skip one (A) and repeat... This will not be as fast as a memcpy but probably pretty close. Combined with some double or triple buffering this should allow you to have a decent execution speed in the end.

Comment: @VB_overflow Yeah, it's worth switching FBO to PBO regardless as there's way less CPU overhead. Do you think it's worth implementing RGBA -> RGB with SIMDs? Or it's purely bandwidth bound and will make no difference?

Comment: I am not an expert in SIMD on IOS (Neon instruction set) but at first sight I would say that you would not gain much from those for simple RGBA to RGB "strided memcopy" as the compiler will probably already optimize the loop pretty well (you compile in 64bit right ?).

Answer (score 1):

According the OpenGL 3.0 specification, GL_RGB is not a valid value for *format.*

https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glReadPixels.xhtml

You may want to either convert it to RGB after retrieving the GL_RGBA formatted buffer, or adjusting your algorithm to compensate for RGBA.

Comment: So, there's no way to do it on the GPU?

Comment: I'm unsure of how your algorithm works, but if you are aiming to do it entirely on the GPU using GLSL, you could do this as two passes. In the first pass, you can render the scene to a texture, and in the second pass run your algorithm. The output could be to the screen and use glReadPixels to read the values, or you can write to a uniform variable and read it from the shader after it runs.

Comment: I was talking about getting GL_RGB8 buffer... Maybe if I switch to Metal there will be a way. It's really silly that on iOS exotic thing like GL_RED works fine, but GL_RGB doesn't... But I guess my use case is quite unique. I think I'll just have to hack neural network to accept RGBA and skip over alpha, but it's going to be quite ugly and hacky

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a CPU solution (glReadPixels or equivalent) and not a GPU solution (shaders). If the format of the pixels is the issue, I would suggest looking into OpenCV. You could get the buffer using GL_RGBA, and quickly and easily convert it to an RGB image. Good luck!